# Drawing method used by panels

Tags: c#

I'm creating Monopoly game in C# and it's my first bigger project. The game consist of panels as fields (cities, events etc.). Player is represented as rectangle drawn on panel and here is a problem. The table of positions store information about position of each player and then i'm comparing each element of table in paint method of each panel (there is 21 panels, what gives 84 'if' statements). For example:

```
private void panel4_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        Pen redpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
        Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 10, 120, 120);
        g.DrawEllipse(redpen, rectangle);

        if (position[0] == 3)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(blackbrush, new Rectangle(110, 110, 20, 20));
        }
        if (position[1] == 3)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(yellowbrush, new Rectangle(80, 110, 20, 20));
        }
        if (position[2] == 3)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(redbrush, new Rectangle(50, 110, 20, 20));
        }
        if (position[3] == 3)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(bluebrush, new Rectangle(20, 110, 20, 20));
        }

    }
```

Is any shorter way to achieve that? I'm planning to add houses and hotels, so it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Consider using one or more a lists of rectangles.. Also: You can combine the paint events of all Panels into one and use the `sender` param to tell them apart.

Comment: Derive your own class from Control, call it MonopolyTile.  Override its OnPaint() method.  Add the Title, Image, Orientation, Houses, Hotels, Players properties, plus whatever else you need.

Comment: I think that you can use a grid, then you can use a rectangle with same dimensions, so you can create a method like this:
putHotel(int row, int column) { Rectangle r= new Rectangle (20,20,20,20} ... mygrid.Children.Add(r)}